# Can't open vim in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I recently decided to switch from zsh to bash. However, for some reason that escapes me, I cannot open vim within zsh after I change my default shell to zsh (`chsh -s /bin/zsh`). Currently, my default shell is bash. If I just use `zsh` to enter a zsh shell, I have no problems with vim. The problems arise when I try to change my default shell, then open a new terminal window. Any insight would be great as I'd love to be able to play around with zsh.

Comment: probably best asked on the Unix/Linux exchange. This isn't a programming question. ---- However, it may be worth investigating the `zsh` equivilent of `.bashrc`, `.bash_history`, etc. You likely don't have them created or setup for booting into `zsh` directly, however when you invoke `zsh` from within `bash` it already has the defaults loaded/configured.

Answer (score 1):

`vim` probably lives in a directory that is added to your `PATH` environment variable in one of your `bash` start up files. When you start `zsh` manually, that `PATH` is inherited by `zsh`. When you make `zsh` your default shell, it inherits a `PATH` which is not modified to include the directory for `vim`. In `bash`, type

```
which vim
```

to find out which directory `vim` lives in. Let's say it `/usr/other/bin/`. Then you would add the following to your `.zshenv` file (creating it if necessary):

```
path+=/usr/other/bin
```

New `zsh` sessions should now be able to run `vim`.